# How can I prevent Googlebot from indexing web service URL's?

Tags: googlebot, iis, web-crawlers, bing

I have a problem with googlebot and bingbot accessing our web service. We have a search application created in aspx that is integrated into a drupal website. Users perform searches based on postal code or city through drupal and search query is outputted through aspx. The problem is that google/bing keeps indexing the aspx returned query pages and then we receive 404 errors.

How can I prevent googlebot from indexing the web service. We are on IIS 7.5. Do we setup a rule on the server? I have tried blocking it in robots.txt but am unsure if I have the correct syntax.

```
Disallow: /*?
User-agent: Googlebot
Noindex: /office/default.aspx
Noindex: /?keyword
Noindex: /el​ectronics/locationdetails.aspx?
Noindex: /electronics/communitydetails.aspx?
Noindex: /electronics/Communitylist.aspx?
Noindex: /office/communitysearch.aspx?
Noindex: /Electronics/Communitylist.aspx?
Noindex: /Office/LocationDetails.aspx?
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `robots.txt` file does not appear to conform to the [robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) (you must specify the user agent before the directives and I do not believe that `Noindex` is a valid directive).

Consider the following updates:

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /Office/LocationDetails.aspx
Disallow: /office/default.aspx
Disallow: /Electronics/Communitylist.aspx
Disallow: /electronics/locationdetails.aspx
Disallow: /electronics/Communitydetails.aspx
Disallow: /electronics/communitydetails.aspx
```

... alternatively, you could configure your webserver (or application) to add `noindex`/`none` `X-Robots-Tag` headers where appropriate as described in detail at Google's [Robots meta tag and X-Robots-Tag HTTP header specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) document.

Answer (score 0):

Use "NoINDEX, NOFOLLOW" Meta Robots tag in each pages under the head tag or certain directives under [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) will do the job for you.